# Looking for film or television program with witch hunt set in present day

Tags: story-identification, witches

To complicate matters, I only remember seeing a trailer, and am not sure whether it was for a film or a television series.

The trailer was set in the present time, but it became apparent that in this universe it was a capital offence to practice witchcraft.

The most striking scene I can remember was the demonstration of a "witch execution chamber". This was a white room behind a glass screen. There was a raised stage with a metal grid on the floor, with gas burners underneath, and a metal beam rising from the floor, with manacles to restrain "the accused".

The other scene was a crowd scene with someone in the crowd pointing and accusing another member of the crowd of being a witch.

I would have seen this in late 1999 or early 2000.

Comment: Did the witchcraft in the show involve real magic (like on [Sabrina](https://media.giphy.com/media/zPhkIrJ7Yamuk/giphy.gif)) or was it simply imagined on the part of the community (like in [The Crucible](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/villains/images/2/20/005.png/revision/latest?cb=20140217015500))?

Comment: I don't think in the short trailer I saw that we witnessed any instances of witchcraft actually being practiced, either real or imagined.

Comment: @Robert: Does the clip from *Charmed* remind you of what you are looking for?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots My memory is not very clear, but by the time it was originally broadcast it looks like this might be the one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you might be thinking of Season 2 Episode 2, "[Morality Bites](http://charmed.wikia.com/wiki/Morality_Bites)" of the *Charmed* TV series, which aired October 7, 1999.

> When Phoebe has a premonition of herself being burned to death, the sisters travel ten years into the future to learn what will happen. They discover that she used her powers to kill Cal Greene, causing a local D.A. named Nathaniel Pratt to begin modern-day witch trials as a platform for political office. Meanwhile, Prue and Piper try to save Phoebe, they both are surprised and somewhat disappointed to learn how their lives turned out.

The chamber is grey, not white, and I don't see a grid on the floor other than the platform, but otherwise it matches. I am unsure as to whether there is a crowd accusation scene, and the [official trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ggB5FAhp__w) does not match your memories.

Comment: It fits in with the time that this was originally broadcast, and the gas burner, and pointing looks like what I remember of the "witch accusation scene".